# Char * is always null terminator

Tags: c, kernel, vga

I am trying to implement a VGA print function but I cannot get data to be seen as a non null character. Even if I hardcode data inside this function it will still skip the `while` loop. I have a debug print that will print a `Z` if count is zero and it always prints it and the cursor does not move so I am pretty confident it is not entering the `while` loop

```
void vga_print(char *data, char mode) {

    char *vga = (char *)(VGA_MEM_LOC);

    uint8_t count = 0;
    while (*data != '\0') {
        if (*data == '\n') {
            current_x = 0;
            current_y++;
        } else {
            *vga++ = *data++;
            *vga++ = mode;
            current_x++;
            if (current_x >= screen_x) {
                current_x = 0;
                current_y++;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    // move the cursor
    uint16_t location = current_x + ((current_y) * screen_x);

    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_INDEX, VGA_CURSOR_LOW);
    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_DATA,  location);

    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_INDEX, VGA_CURSOR_HIGH);
    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_DATA,  location >> 8);
}
```

EDIT: If I initialize the data string as `char example[] = "xyz\0"` instead of `char *example = "xyz\0"` it works

Comment: Null terminators are for strings. VGA memory is not a string, it's binary data, so it can contain 0 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that but even when I hardcode ```data``` to something like ```char * data = "Test"``` it still does not print anything

Comment: If you do `printf("%d", strlen(data));` what does it say?

Comment: @Barmar I copy and pasted this code into a full Linux distro compiled it using a dummy vga pointer and it behaved as expected. This is from a partially complete kernel so there is not printf

Comment: If this behaves correctly in a regular kernel, but fails in your kernel, I suspect there's a problem with your kernel. The code as written doesn't have any reason why it would think there's a zero when there isn't.

Comment: If you have a debug print that can print a Z, why can't you use that to print the input string?

Comment: If you want to hardcode `data`, I would create the string with `char str[3]; str[0]='H'; str[1]='i'; str[2]='\0'; data=str;`. That way, there are fewer things that can go wrong. And I would overwrite the value of `mode` too.

Comment: Comment out the whole `while` block. Add some very simple code that just adds a single character. Something like: `current_x = 0; current_y++; *vga = 'H'; vga++; *vga = mode;  vga++;` Does that work?

Comment: @user3386109 I can print a 'Z' by saying that *vga = 'Z' but for some reason of a check a full string it is equal to the null terminator

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yes, that works, a full string is always read as the null terminator thogh, even if it is hardcoded in the `vga_print` function itself

Answer (score 1):

There are problems in the function, but none that explains the observed behavior. There might be something wrong with the initial values of the global variables `current_x`, `current_y` and `screen_x` or the way you call the function from code you did not post.  The definitions of `VGA_CRT_INDEX`, `VGA_CURSOR_LOW`, `VGA_CRT_DATA`, `VGA_CURSOR_HIGH`, `VGA_MEM_LOC` and the function `x86_port_out` might be incorrect too.

Here are some problems:

- all output starts at the base address of the VGA screen buffer.
- `current_x` and `current_y` get updated for each byte and the newline, but the `vga` pointer does not move so the next character appears glued to the previous output.
- you do not increment `data` when `*data == '\n'`: this would cause an infinite loop.
- you do not handle the case where `current_y >= screen_y`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void vga_print(const char *data, unsigned char mode) {

    uint16_t *vga = (uint16_t *)(VGA_MEM_LOC);
    uint16_t location = current_x + current_y * screen_x;
    uint16_t i;
    uint8_t ch;

    while ((ch = *data++) != '\0') {
        if (ch == '\n' || current_x >= screen_x) {
            current_x = 0;
            current_y++;
            location = current_y * screen_x;
        }
        if (current_y >= screen_y) {
            current_y = screen_y - 1;
            location = current_y * screen_x;
            // shift the screen contents up one line
            for (i = 0; i < location; i++)
                vga[i] = vga[i + screen_x];
            }
            // erase the bottom line
            for (i = 0; i < screen_x; i++) {
                vga[location + i] = ' ' | (mode << 8);
            }
            location += screen_x;
        }
        if (ch != '\n') {
            vga[location++] = ch | (mode << 8);
            current_x++;
        }
    }

    // move the cursor
    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_INDEX, VGA_CURSOR_LOW);
    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_DATA, (uint8_t)location);

    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_INDEX, VGA_CURSOR_HIGH);
    x86_port_out(VGA_CRT_DATA, (uint8_t)(location >> 8));
}
```

Comment: I was aware of these issues but was more concerned with just getting it to print to the screen first. This modified version suffers from the same issue as the original (I did remove `memmove` because there is no `string.h`

Comment: Actually, upon further review this code will never work. the second `if` needs to be up one scope

Comment: @RJYarwood I fixed this but it does not seem to be correctly incrementing `location` as it is just printing in the first location.

Comment: @RJYarwood: I fixed the code in the answer, but can you post the missing definitions? Can you also document the compiler and memory model details?